# connecting to mongo replica set from EC2

Tags: php, mongodb, amazon-ec2

I am trying to connect to a mongo replica set using PHP,

my code looks like this:

```
$options = array(
                'replicaSet' => 'Repset',
                'readPreference' => 'primaryPreferred',
        );
        $connection = new MongoClient("mongodb://ip-10-1-2-3.ec2.internal:27017,ip-10-1-2-4.ec2.internal:27017/", $options);
```

When I do this I get an error back:

```
No candidate servers found
```

if I simplify the connect string to :

```
$connection = new MongoClient("mongodb://ip-10-1-2-4.ec2.internal:27017/");
```

Then it connects to the server, but this is not the right way, given I am using replica Sets

What am I doing wrong, the connect script seems right but obviously isn't.

Would appreciate any help.

Comment: Are you sufre you setup your replica named as `RepSet` and that it is running? Only other thing I can think of is that you are using the internal routing which does not work from PHP, you must assign IP addresses to your EC2 instances.

Comment: If I use the mongo command from ssh and type rs.status() it comes up as I think it should.

Did not know that PHP would not talk to internal IP addresses. I will take a look at that side of things. Thanks!

Answer (score -1):

Have you tried to delete space before $options?